# Speedup of CPU Pipelining by number of steps

Tags: performance, acceleration

When a CPU has $K$ steps the speed up of using pipelining compared to non-pipelining is $K$. But what I want to know is, say I am a CPU designer and want to decide whether I should build $K$ or $N$ steps, how do I know the speedup between having $K$ or $N$ steps?

I figured that the theoretical speed would be the same and the only possible speedup is when steps can be implemented with simpler circuits, thus increasing the clock speed. Am I right with this, assuming that the two designs only differ by number of steps?

Another point is, how do more steps influence the real-time aspect of processing? Since more steps means waiting long, is there a point, when the pipelining may have a bad impact on the system stability? Bechaus essential what Pipelining does is to value throughput more than speed.

Comment: That's a general CS question, but in short, there is a price to pay with more stages (namely, more transistors) while the payoff diminishes (because the pipeline's contents have to be discarded at all branches that you can't correctly predict.